# How to animate camera around a water simulation?

Tags: animation

I have just created a water fountain with a water simulation creating the water sprouting out. I would like to Animate the camera around the water fountain while it is flowing water from its sprout.  I have tried key framing all the movements but they do not register, and I just end up with a stationary shot of the fountain sprouting water.
Can anyone help with how to set this up to work, or point me to a video on the technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to control a camera is to use a curve object:

- Create a **Curve** object and modify it as you like. This will be the path where the camera will move
- On the camera create a **Follow Path** constraint, set the curve as the *Target*, and you might want to tick the *Fixed Position* checkbox
- To make it easier to control the camera direction, create a new empty (I like the sphere one)
- Add a **Track To** constraint on the camera and set the empty as *Target*. The orientation is *To: -Z* and *Up: Y*
- To animate, create 2 keyframes on the Offset slider in the **Follow Path** constraint

[image]

This way, when you change the *Offset* value the camera will move on the path, and it will always look at the empty.
In your case, put the empty on the water simulation and shape the path as a spiral around it to get a beautiful cinematic camera animation. (The empty can be animated as well if you want)

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. Eevee just renders the water simulation and ignors all the camera tracking animation keyframes.

Comment: Yes what you suggested does work its just that I forgot to select the camera object first.

Comment: If it worked, please accept my answer as the correct one (the green tick symbol) to close this topic